# adding controller to tabs in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs

So I am using this example https://jsfiddle.net/jccrosby/eRGT8/ to created tabbed spa. So far this is working but when i try to add separate controller combining http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/pj5br/ like below, i am losing even the original tabs.

```
<div ng-app="TabsApp">
<div id="tabs" ng-controller="TabsCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" 
            ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(tab.url)}" 
            ng-click="onClickTab(tab)">{{tab.title}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="mainView">
        <div ng-include="currentTab"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="one.tpl.html">
    <div id="viewOne" >
        <h1>View One</h1>
        <p>1.</p>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="two.tpl.html">
    <div id="viewTwo" ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
        <h1>View Two</h1>
            <p>Click <a ng-click="loadPeople()">here</a> to load</p>
  <table>
  <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
      <td>{{person.id}}</td>
      <td>{{person.firstName}}</td>
      <td>{{person.lastName}}</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="three.tpl.html">
    <div id="viewThree">
        <h1>View Three</h1>
        <p>3.</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

js file

```
var mockDataForThisTest = "json=" + encodeURI(JSON.stringify([
{
id: 1,
firstName: "Peter",
lastName: "Jhons"},
{
id: 2,
firstName: "David",
lastName: "Bowie"}
]));

var app = angular.module('TabsApp', []);
app.controller('TabsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.tabs = [{
        title: 'One',
        url: 'one.tpl.html'
    }, {
        title: 'Two',
        url: 'two.tpl.html'
    }, {
        title: 'Three',
        url: 'three.tpl.html'
}];

$scope.currentTab = 'one.tpl.html';

$scope.onClickTab = function (tab) {
    $scope.currentTab = tab.url;
}

$scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
    return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
}
}]);
app.controller('PeopleCtrl',['$scope','$http',function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.people = [];

$scope.loadPeople = function() {
    var httpRequest = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: mockDataForThisTest

    }).success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.people = data;
    });

};

}]};
```

output like:
below showing just 1 tab and nothing else

```
{{tab.title}}
```

So i need the 2nd example working inside the 2nd tab. new to Angular js so trying out. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Here is the sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/gen14rp5/

Answer (score 1):

angular js library is not added just add the library reference to the fiddle

Comment: sorry missed it but the issue is not related to it. I am running it locally

Comment: yes, fixes the issue but this has the values directly assigned? anyway to use the httpRequest as given in the example 2

Comment: here i did some changes check it out :)
    https://plnkr.co/edit/8MOquxlcrVsU0Cm2SVxY?p=preview